# Node js - cant install packages on a server

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

I want to have grunt on my server, and via hook, i want the server to run a grunt task that will "build" my site.

I installed node on my server, and i installed grunt-cli using this:

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs 
$ sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
```

then, i go to my project folder, which is where my package.json and gruntfile.js files are located.

im using **npm install** and then, i see /node_modules folder but i don't see the packages there.
I don't see any error. Do you know why this happens? perhaps server configuration?

> package.json

```
{
  "name": "proj",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular": "latest",
    "angular-animate": "latest",
    "angular-ui-router": "latest",
    "font-awesome": "^4.5.0",
    "grunt": "latest",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "latest"
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the content of your package.json ? , it specify dependencies?

Comment: yes, i will upload and edit my message. * done

Answer (score 0):

> With the --production flag (or when the NODE_ENV environment variable is set to production), npm will not install modules listed in devDependencies.

source: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#description

Since you're on a server, I assume, this is a production one and `NODE_ENV` is set to `production`. To install both `dependencies` & `devDependencies`, run:

```
NODE_ENV=dev npm install
```